# The parameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:run are missing or invalid

Tags: gwt, maven-2

I have created gwt maven project now I want to compile it and run it. To comiple I am providing `gwt:compile` as goal and to run `gwt:run` but it is giving me build failure with exception:

> [INFO]  [INFO] >>> gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:run (default-cli) @
>    engilev2_with_maven >>> [INFO]
>   [INFO] ---
>    maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @
>    engilev2_with_maven --- [debug] execute contextualize
>   [INFO] Using
>    'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
>   [INFO] Copying 3
>    resources [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ engilev2_with_maven ---
>   [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /root/18julyWorkspace/engilev2_with_maven/target/EngileNightly/WEB-INF/classes
>   [INFO] <<< gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:run (default-cli) @ engilev2_with_maven <<< [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:run (default-cli) @ engilev2_with_maven ---
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 4.128s [INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 27 12:01:34 IST 2012
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/131M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [WARNING] The requested profile "default" could not be activated because it does not exist.
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:run (default-cli) on project
>   engilev2_with_maven: The parameters 'runTarget' for goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:run are missing or invalid ->
>   [Help 1] [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X
>   switch to enable full debug logging.

I don't understand what problem here

Pom.xml :::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>engilev2_with_maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>engilev2_with_maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

    <properties>
        <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
        <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
        <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId> <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId> 
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId> <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId> 
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>appops_shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>appops_shared</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>appops_client</groupId>
            <artifactId>appops_client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>appops_server</groupId>
            <artifactId>appops_server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local.mvp4g</groupId>
            <artifactId>mvp4g</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId> 
            <version>3.0</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtupload</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId> 
            <version>1.6.1</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtphonegap</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtphonegap</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-poll</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-tomcat7</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-jbossweb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assisted-inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>atmosphere-gwt-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>gwt-oauth2</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
            <classifier>alpha</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>EngileNightly</finalName>
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <!-- <versionRange>[2.5.0,)</versionRange> -->
                                    <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <modules>
                                            <module>com.engile.Engile</module>
                                        </modules>
                                    </configuration>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                                    </goals>

                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>

                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Add your pom.xml too please.

Comment: I have edited my question plz have a look.

Comment: Any particular reason plugin - gwt-maven-plugin is not configured?

Comment: there is no specific reason for that .. is it because of that ? which configurations are needed over there.

Comment: Check out how to set up a pom.xml from gwt sample projects - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure `<runTarget>` tag under `<plugin>` tag for `<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>`

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                    documentation at codehaus.org -->
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Check GWT Sample project sample for how to set up maven gwt projects http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/

GWT and WorkingWithMaven - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Mavem proprties:
`mvn gwt:run -DrunTarget=Application.jsp`