# Run maven gwt application in hosted mode

Tags: gwt, maven

I have created gwt maven project and I want run it so from command line I am providing:

```
mvn compile gwt:run -DrunTarget=com.engile.Engile/Engile.html
```

But In logs it shows:

```
ava.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1847)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at com.appops.server.data.hibernate.SessionProvider.createSessionFactory(SessionProvider.java:46)
    at com.appops.server.data.hibernate.HibernateDataSourceConnector.init(HibernateDataSourceConnector.java:39)
    at com.engile.server.services.ConfigurationServlet.init(ConfigurationServlet.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:102)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4363)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
```

and pom.xml includes:

```
<properties>
        <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
        <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
        <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <!-- <versionRange>[2.5.0,)</versionRange> -->
                                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>resources</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <goal>i18n</goal>
                                    <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                                </goals>

                                <configuration>
                                    <runTarget>Engile.html</runTarget>
                                    <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName} </hostedWebapp>
                                    <modules>
                                        <module>com.engile.Engile</module>
                                    </modules>
                                    <!-- <runTarget>com.engile.Engile/Engile.html</runTarget> -->
                                </configuration>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[2.1.1,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exploded</goal>
                                </goals>

                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In build path in source section I am providing outputfolder of src/main/java is target/classes and default output folder is:

engilev2_with_mavenold/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes

is anything is wrong, I don't understand the webapp/classes folder and target/classes folder where java classes are compiled to ?

Comment: this exception came just because of jar compatibility...  Plz ensure the correct versions of jars before using.. that solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

**You have not configured gwt-maven-plugin in your build tag.** You are only configuring maven-compiler-plugin and lifecycle-mapping plugin. The gwt-maven-plugin under lifecycle-plugin is only to inform eclipse to avoid invoking gwt compilation in refresh cycles,

You have the same issue in the other stackoverflow question too -
[The parameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:run are missing or invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050476/the-parameters-runtarget-for-goal-org-codehaus-mojogwt-maven-plugin2-5-0run)

Add another plugin tag in your pom.xml under buil tag after maven-compiler-plugin

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- <versionRange>[2.5.0,)</versionRange> -->
                        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>i18n</goal>
                            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <runTarget>Engile.html</runTarget>
                            <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName} </hostedWebapp>
                            <modules>
                                <module>com.engile.Engile</module>
                            </modules>
                            <!-- <runTarget>com.engile.Engile/Engile.html</runTarget> -->
                        </configuration>
</plugin>
```